# How can I get the info of an image with exifinterface in the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-exifinterface

```
Uri uri = ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File(path).toString()));
gfgIn = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(gfgIn);
```

The code above isn't work in my fragment. How can I rewrite it ?

Comment: change `new ExifInterface(uri)` to `new ExifInterface(gfgIn)`

Comment: `Uri uri;` No, that will not work. You should assign a value first.

Comment: Sorry that is old version. I update it

Answer (score 0):

Like most Android SDK classes, [`ExifInterface` has documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface). In particular, that documentation contains [a list of public constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#public-constructors).

[The first such constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#ExifInterface(java.io.File)) takes a `File` as its sole constructor parameter.

You appear to be looking to get this information from a `File`, identified by a variable named `path`.

So, use `new ExifInterface(path)`.

Comment: how I can show all info of image when I use ExifInterface?

Comment: @MrD: I do not know what you mean by that, sorry.

Comment: I want to show the information of an image. But when I implement exifinterface, I don't know how to show the attribute in it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61WB0ArIpUs 
Like this video @CommonsWare